# Being given zip archives with .git - how to integrate into own Git repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I have purchased an iOS game template and received the source code as a zip-archive including .git subdirectory of the author developer:

[image: screenshot]

Then I have created my own BitBucket repository.

How should I put the new files there and how to integrate the Git history of the files with the history of my new repository?

Should I use branches here and whose changes should be at the "master" branch - mine or his?

Comment: What is your intended workflow?  Will you feed changes back to the author, or do you consider yourself on your own now?

Comment: My workflow will be that I will perform most of the future development work, but I think I will receive few more zip-archives with changes by the original author (intended not just for me, but for all buyers of his template) - and I wonder how to handle the future zip-archives, how to merge his changes into mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) is what you are looking for.

That means, you could integrate that Git repository from your screenshot into your repository like this:

**Demo setup**

My project repository is located at:

```
/Users/Me/Desktop/MyProject
```

The iOS game template library you bought is located at:

```
/Users/Me/Desktop/TemplateProject
```

**Your repository**

```
git init
touch YourCodeFile1 # Just as example placeholder file
touch YourCodeFile2 # Just as example placeholder file
```

**Integrating iOS template repository as Git submodule**

```
git submodule add /Users/Me/Desktop/TemplateProject
ls -l

drwxr-xr-x  5 Me  staff  170 Mar  1 12:06 TemplateProject
-rw-r--r--  1 Me  staff    0 Mar  1 12:03 YourCodeFile1
-rw-r--r--  1 Me  staff    0 Mar  1 12:03 YourCodeFile2
```

**Integrating new ZIP archives**

When you receive new ZIP archives, you can unzip it over the old location

```
/Users/Me/Desktop/TemplateProject
```

and then, from within your repository, do this:

```
git submodule update --remote TemplateProject
```

Answer (score 1):

> How should I put the new files there and how to integrate the Git history of the files with the history of my new repository?

This depends entirely on how you intend to use the code being given to you.

If it's a library, it probably doesn't need to go in your repository. Check it out elsewhere on disk, and link to it through what ever means your programming language provides.

If it's a template that you're meant to build on-top of, just do that. Don't create your own repository, just work directly on his - it's yours now.  Commit your changes as normal. You'll be able to merge any of his changes into the repository at a later point in time.

Comment: Please elaborate your last sentence - how can I merge the future improvements of his game template (not library, but an iOS app) into my work?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Assuming that the directory you show us in your screenshot is "Repo A", and that you've been working on it. When he sends you another zip, extract it elsewhere on disk, call that "Repo B". From A, you would add B as a remote, run a `git fetch`, and then merge the appropriate branch.